# Retrieve data returned from USSD Codes Android

Tags: android, call, ussd, imei

I am trying to **dial USSD code** for **IMEI** from within my android app **bypassing the default android caller** and trying to **retrieve the response** from it, parse it and use it further.
I wish to get information returned from ussd code in the callback and use it further.

I tried the following things : 
1. **Analytical Services**
2. the below code -

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Handler handler = new Handler();

            TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback responseCallback = new TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveUssdResponse(TelephonyManager telephonyManager, String request, CharSequence response) {
                    super.onReceiveUssdResponse(telephonyManager, request, response);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceiveUssdResponseFailed(TelephonyManager telephonyManager, String request, int failureCode) {
                    super.onReceiveUssdResponseFailed(telephonyManager, request, failureCode);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(failureCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };

            telephonyManager.sendUssdRequest("*#06#", responseCallback, handler);
```

**Issues faced :** 
1. Not able to run USSD codes.
2. Callback is always of failure.

What can be done to achieve this?

Comment: hey, same here. Have you ever find a solution to this?